# Processing and stop() method

Tags: processing

I want to perform some operations when quitting a Processing sketch. I found on forums that method stop() is called before the application quits.
I tried it, but it seems to me it is never called.
Here follows a minimal (not working) example:

```
void setup()
{
 size(100, 100);
 println("start");
}

void draw()
{
  //nothing here
}

void stop()
{
  println("called stop()");
  super.stop();
}
```

When quitting the application , through stop button on the IDE or
through X button on App, I never see the message "called stop()".
I tried both with and without super.stop(), nothing changes. 
Thanks

Processing 2.2.1, on Linux Debian Wheezy

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9548/stop-method-does-not-work

Answer (score 3):

The stop() function is a leftover from the fact that PApplet extends Applet. Unless you're deploying as an applet, the stop() function will never be called. Even if you are deploying as an applet, the stop() function is still not guaranteed to be called! More info in the [PApplet API](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#stop()).

Assuming you're using Java mode, you might look into adding a **shutdown hook**, or just add a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to your frame.

Comment: I looked for some example applied to Processing but did'n find. It seems to me this operation is more complicated than expected...

Comment: @valerio_sperati I've mentioned 2 approaches. What happened when you tried them?

Comment: I was looking on Google for some example about "shutdown hook" or "WindowListener" applied to Processing, but did'n t find yet.  Continuing the search!

Comment: @valerio_sperati If you're using Java mode, you can just use the Java code for a WindowListener or a shutdown hook. You don't need to find code specific to Processing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kevin's answer, you an override the `exit()` method:

```
void setup(){
  println("start");
}
void draw(){}
void exit(){
  println("stop");//do your thing on exit here
  super.exit();//let processing carry with it's regular exit routine
}
```